# Does TrackPopupMenu "harm" my HMENU?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, contextmenu, trayicon

Heya. Finally, after a lot of fiddling, I got a .rc-loaded context menu for my tray notify icon working. (Dialog based Windows API application, no MFC). However, in the various examples and usage demonstrations I always saw that the `HMENU` is being created (`CreateMenu()`, `LoadMenu()`) and destroyed (`DestroyMenu()`) **right before/right after** the call to `TrackPopupMenu()`. Popup menus for notify icons are, like, not at all documented on MSDN (at least I haven't found more than a single paragraph about them).

Intuitively, I put the `LoadMenu()` in the message handling for `WM_INITDIALOG` and store the `HMENU`, so I don't have to create and destroy the menu every time. As I said, I haven't found any examples where this is done similarly, which I find a bit intriguing. Is it possible that my `HMENU` would ever get "corrupted" while using the menu or the application? Or is it safe to go for the (well, marginal) extra performance as I do?

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MainDlg(HWND ..., UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        ...
        HMENU hMenuBar = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_NOTIFYMENU));
        hNotifyMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0);
        ...
        break;

    ...

    case WM_NOTIFYICON:
        switch (lParam)
        {
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:        // there is no WM_CONTEXTMENU for 
            {                     // nid.uVersion != NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4
            POINT CursorPos;
            GetCursorPos(&CursorPos);

            // this is where I saw LoadMenu and stuff in examples

            SetForegroundWindow(hDlg); // otherwise menu won't disappear
            TrackPopupMenu(hNotifyMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN, CursorPos.x,
                           CursorPos.y, 0, hDlg, NULL);

            PostMessage(hDlg, WM_NULL, 0, 0); // otherwise menu locks hDlg

            // this is where I saw DestroyMenu in examples
            }

            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that it gets corrupted, it's more that you don't want to hold GDI resources longer than absolutely necessary. You can easily run out of them, just look at Chrome that struggled with GDI resource limits for months before finally finding a work around.

Besides loading a menu a dozen times and destroying it is nothing for a modern day processor. Don't prematurely optimize programs, especially not for so little gain.

As to why you haven't found any MSDN pages dealing specifically with notification icons' menus, that's because they're two separate things. A menu is a menu, whether it's on top of a dialog, popping up when you right click a textbox or when you right click a notification icon. You don't need special advice or code for either.

Comment: I see, I haven't looked at it this way. Thanks for the info. So, would [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647558%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Displaying_a_Shortcut_Menu) not be kind of a severe leak then? Since it doesn't destroy `hmenuTrackPopup`.

Comment: What do you mean? It gets destroyed from the parent's handle.

Comment: So `GetSubMenu()` merely retrieves the handle and doesn't create a fully qualified menu equally to `CreateMenu()` then - got it! Thanks.